# Seq2Seq: Decoder predictions not depends on Encoder inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

I'm training Seq2Seq model on OpenSubtitles dialogs - [Cornell-Movie-Dialogs-Corpus](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~cristian/Cornell_Movie-Dialogs_Corpus.html).

My work based on the following papers:

- (1) [*Sequence to Sequence Learning with Neural Networks, Sutskever et al. 2014*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3215)
- (2) [*A Neural Conversational Model, Vinyals, Le, 2015*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.05869)

The training converges well, but when I checked what the network is actually predicting - I discovered that the `encoder`'s input doesn't matter at all for `decoder`'s predictions. What matters are only words presented to the `decoder`.

For example after the tag `<s>` the `decoder` predicts always the word 'i'.

The pseudo-code of my architecture looks like this (I'm using Tensorflow 1.5):

```
seq1 = tf.placeholder(...)
seq2 = tf.placeholder(...)

embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocab_size, 300]))

seq1_emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, seq1)
seq2_emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, seq2)

# Encoder init_state is a random_uniform of: -0.08, 0.08 (according to paper [1])

encoder_out, state1 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(BasicLSTMCell(), seq1_emb)
decoder_out, state2 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(BasicLSTMCell(), seq2_emb,
                                                        initial_state=state_1)
logit = Dense(decoder_out, use_bias=False)

crossent = tf.nn.saparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logit, 
                                                         labels=target)
crossent = mask_padded_zeros(crossent)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(crossent) / number_of_words_in_batch

# Gradient is Clipped-By-Norm with 5 (according to paper [1])

train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.7).minimize(loss)
```

I would be very glad for your help!

Comment: To clarify -- you always see the same prediction, no matter the source sentence?

Comment: Yes, matters only the text (or init-sentence-tag) presented to the `decoder`

Comment: In you 4th line, you define `seq2_emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, seq1)`. Should be `seq2_emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, seq2)`

Comment: Yes, but it's just a typo, since it is only a pseudo-code. In my actual implementation it's fine - I double checked :)